# Template deduction fails when using std::result_of<F>

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I am trying to make a function which calls and return the returned value of a function passed as a template parameter:

```cpp
template <typename Function>
typename std::result_of<Function>::type
call_function(Function&& f)
{
  return f();
}

template <typename Function, typename Class>
typename std::result_of<Function>::type
call_member_function(Function&& f, Class* instance)
{
  return instance->*f();
}

//
// call site:
//

call_function(f);
call_member_function(&F::f, &instance);
```

Here is a ideone version: http://ideone.com/IYM10x (it fails in a similar way in VS2013.4)

I have substituted the argument to `std::result_of` to different permutations of `std::decay`, `std::remove_reference` and `std::remove_pointer` without any luck.

How do I make `call_function` and `call_member_function` compile, preferably also for functions which return `void`?

Comment: If that's how `result_of` worked, what would you expect `std::result_of<F>::type` to be when `F` is a functor with an overloaded `operator()` ? You can't ask "what is the result of calling F?" you can only say "what is the result of calling F with these arguments?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to apply a `std::remove_reference` or a `std::decay` transformation to a deduced `Function` type so as to use it with `std::result_of`. What you need is a proper syntax similar to a *function call expression*:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename Function>
auto call_function(Function&& f)
    -> typename std::result_of<Function()>::type
//                                     ~^
{
    return std::forward<Function>(f)();
}

template <typename Function, typename Class>
auto call_member_function(Function&& f, Class* instance)
    -> typename std::result_of<Function(Class*)>::type
//                                     ~~~~~~~^
{
    return (instance->*std::forward<Function>(f))();
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a632f5eaf67ffcc)

---

> *How do I make this work for functions of with different number of arguments?*

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename Function, typename... Args>
auto call_function(Function&& f, Args&&... args)
    -> typename std::result_of<Function(Args...)>::type
{
    return std::forward<Function>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename Function, typename Class, typename... Args>
auto call_member_function(Function&& f, Class* instance, Args&&... args)
    -> typename std::result_of<Function(Class*, Args...)>::type
{
    return (instance->*std::forward<Function>(f))(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4750900b900fc1ed)

---

> *The argument list (Args...) should already be part of Function, why do I need them again? Or rather is there a way to make std::result_of<> work without them?*

Yes, a list of parameters is already a part of the deduced `Function` signature. The trick is, this is not how `std::result_of<F>` works - it only utilizes the syntax of a function declaration.

`std::result_of<F>` is designed to query the result type of a given functor object when called with arguments of given types.

What normally would be the *result type* of a function, like `int` for `int(char,float)`, within `std::result_of` it is treated as the type of a functor object that a function call operator will be applied to. Hence, when you have a `Function` defined as follows:

```
using Function = int(char,float);
```

then the `std::result_of<Function>::type` is equal to:

```
std::result_of<int(char,float)>::type
//              |    |    |
//              |    |    `~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
//              |    `~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.                      | 
//              `~~~~~~~~.                     |                      |
//                       V                     V                      V
decltype(  std::declval<int>() ( std::declval<char>(), std::declval<float>() )  )
//                ^            ^               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
//    instance of a functor   call operator        arguments
```

That is, the *result type* deduced in a partial specialization of `std::result_of` is used to obtain an instance of a functor object. Since there is no function call operator for `int` defined, the above attempt fails to compile.

If the `Function` is deduced as a *reference to function*, then you end up with an incomplete primary template of `std::result_of`, because it doesn't even match any of its partial specializations.

If you want to get the return type of a function (without providing the arguments first, so `decltype()` is not an option), you can deduce it during the function template argument deduction:

```
template <typename R, typename... Params, typename... Args>
R call_function(R(*f)(Params...), Args&&... args)
{
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename R, typename Class, typename... Params, typename... Args>
R call_member_function(R(Class::*f)(Params...), Class* instance, Args&&... args)
{
    return (instance->*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

or by providing a separate trait class:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename F>
struct return_type;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(Args...)> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(*)(Args...)> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...)> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) &> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) &&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) const> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) const&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) const&&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) volatile> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) volatile&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) volatile&&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile&&> { using type = R; };

template <typename Function, typename... Args>
auto call_function(Function&& f, Args&&... args)
    -> typename return_type<typename std::remove_reference<Function>::type>::type
{
    return std::forward<Function>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename Function, typename Class, typename... Args>
auto call_member_function(Function&& f, Class* instance, Args&&... args)
    -> typename return_type<typename std::remove_reference<Function>::type>::type
{
    return (instance->*std::forward<Function>(f))(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[**DEMO 3**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f0095cdf635eb32)

Comment: Or simply use `-> decltype(f())`, `-> decltype((instance->*f)())`.

Comment: How do I make this work for functions of with different number of arguments? (ignore the return-statement for now, I have that implemented in a different way)

Comment: The argument list (Args...) should already be part of Function, why do I need them again? Or rather is there a way to make std::result_of<> work without them? I do not have access to the arguments (only part of the type of Function).

Comment: @PiotrS. your answer is obviously correct given the formulation of my current question so I am going to accept it and ask a different question - thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't forward the member function ?

Comment: I believe that `std::result_of<F(Args&&...)>::type` is identical to `std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type` -- the `&&` are noise.  Am I mistaken?  Oh, and hopefully OP can add `return_type< R(T::*)(Args...) >` to take a member function pointer.

Comment: @Yakk yes, it's redundant for `&&`

Comment: @mauve I would reconsider: function objects that contain overloads are going to be increasingly common in C++14, and you probably know what arguments you will call `F` with.  By using result of and giving it args, the overload can be resolved, and it works for both `[](auto&&x)` lambdas and function pointers.

Comment: @Yakk and I wanted to avoid adding all cv-ref variations of `R(T::*)(Args...)`. it was added just to show the basic example of how this could be done.

Comment: @PioterS. Wow: that is getting painful.  Wonder if we need new syntax there?

Comment: @PiotrS. thanks for v3, it was exactly what I was looking for. Your answer is incredibly good, I just wish I could upvote it several times :D