# using std::result_of to determine the return type of a template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I think the snippet of code is self explanatory, but basically the template function `ExecFunc` should be able to execute another function and return its result. I know I can achieve similar results using `decltype` instead of `result_of`, but this question is to understand *why* what I've written does not work: the snippet does not compile on gcc v4.9.2.

This is what I have:

```
#include <type_traits>

int f(int i)
{
   return i;
}

template<class F, class T>
auto ExecFunc(F f, T arg) -> typename std::result_of<F()>::type
{
  return f(arg);
}

int main() {
   auto a = ExecFunc(f, 3);
   return 0;
}
```

and this is the compiler output:

```
prova.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prova.cpp:15:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘ExecFunc(int (&)(int), int)’
auto a = ExecFunc(f, 3);
                      ^
prova.cpp:15:26: note: candidate is:
prova.cpp:9:6: note: template<class F, class T> typename std::result_of<F()>::type ExecFunc(F, T)
 auto ExecFunc(F f, T arg) -> typename std::result_of<F()>::type
      ^
prova.cpp:9:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prova.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class F, class T> typename std::result_of<F()>::type ExecFunc(F, T) [with F = int (*)(int); T = int]’:
prova.cpp:15:26:   required from here
prova.cpp:9:6: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<int (*())(int)>’
```

N.B.
this question might look like a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27667603/template-deduction-fails-when-using-stdresult-off) but the accepted solution doesn't work for me (at least, as far as I can tell I have incorporated the solution in my code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you have is `int f(int i)` but you are calling `F()` which is unknown.  `std::result_of<F()>::type` should be `std::result_of<F(T)>::type`.

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc70e5ec301dec12)

Comment: do you suggest I call `std::result_of<f()>`? that doesn't work either, and after all you have to pass a type as template argument, not an expression

Comment: thanks, follow-up question if you don't mind: what would be the correct syntax if as return type of `ExecFunc` I wanted an `std::queue<std::result_of<F(T)>>`?

p.s. I'll accept this answer as it was the first and most complete

Comment: @blue You could do it like this with `result_of`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4583b5d3dcad443f

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the parameter of `result_of`, it should be:

```
-> typename std::result_of<F(T)>::type
```

Comment: The result is `F` either way, no?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit huh?  Why would it be `F`?  It is roughly `std::declval<F>()(std::declval<T>())`, which is not going to be `F` (aside: it would be an challeng for that to be `F`), and is utterly different than `std::declval<F>()()`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I didn't think it required much elaboration.  Added, just in case that helps.

Comment: @Yakk Honestly, I don't really care. Feel free to write an answer or something. I'll just delete my stupid comment and leave this nonsense alone.

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect time to use `decltype`

```
template<class F, class T>
auto ExecFunc(F f, T arg) -> decltype(f(arg))
```